# Android 13 can not load ebpf kporbe program

Tags: ebpf

For aosp 13. I have two ebpf program. one is tracepoint type, another is kprobe type. traceponit works well. But kprobe program when compile successful, and push to /system/etc/bpf/, after reboot. It not auto load to the /sys/fs/bpf/

my example very sample :

```
DEFINE_BPF_PROG("kprobe/tcp_sendmsg", AID_ROOT, AID_ROOT, kb_do_tcp_sendmsg)  
(void *ctx){
    return 0;      
}
```

my kernel is 4.19.190. the CONFIG_KPROBE is y.

Comment: Do you have any error message or code?

Comment: No , I try to debug bpfloader.cpp（Add some log).  but aosp load bpf program in the reboot progress。 The log was not printed. I want know if aosp  has some limit for kprobe of ebpf.

Answer (score 0):

how about this one.

```
SEC("kprobe/tcp_sendmsg")
int kprobe__ tcp_sendmsg(void *ctx){
    return 0;      
}
```

---

I‘m also working on eBPF kprobe on android, want to attach to ip_finish_output, currently stuck at how to include skbuff.h header...

Comment: ```
SEC("kprobe/tcp_sendmsg")
int kprobe__ tcp_sendmsg(struct pt_reg *ctx){
    return 0;      
} 
```